# Add an autoincremental number to SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have a table like the following.

```
CREATE TABLE animal
(
    name VARCHAR (50), 
);

INSERT INTO animal VALUES ('Cat');
INSERT INTO animal VALUES ('Dog');
INSERT INTO animal VALUES ('Elephant');
```

Is there a way to place an autoincrement column in such a way that the result is as follows?

```
1,Cat
2,Dog
3,Elephant
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at an identity column? CREATE TABLE [dbo].[animal]([id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, [name] [varchar](50) NULL);

Comment: @Tarzan Thank you, but this is a very brief example. I needed to create an "identity" field only for specific queries, not the actual ID of the table.

Comment: Usually dbms offer and autoincrement option on a specific column which you can set when creating a table, something like: create table animals (animalid int not null auto_increment,...) if that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Row_Number()

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [name]) RowNum, [name]
FROM animal;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `row_number()` :

```
select row_number() over(order by (select null)) as id, name
from animal;
```